# Disconnect my sensor and converting sensor result to distance measurement meter on C#

Tags: c#

I am facing two problem in this my program please help me to find out. I am trying to develop a program for RS-422 sensor by using C#.

All the data is displaying in text area but I want that data in meter form, I searched a lot about that but I didn't find any solution. If you have any idea to convert sensor default data in a meter form please give me some solution.

And another problem is I wanted to disconnect my sensor with disconnect button but my code is not working to disconnect. Please help me to solve this.

This my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace WindowsFormsApp9
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label3.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
            label4.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort aSerialPort = new SerialPort("COM4");
            aSerialPort.BaudRate = 19200;
            aSerialPort.DataBits = 7;
            aSerialPort.Parity = Parity.Even;
            aSerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            aSerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialDataReceivedEventHandler);
            button1.Enabled = false;
            button2.Enabled = true;

            if (aSerialPort.IsOpen == false)
            {
                aSerialPort.Open();
            }
        }

        private void serialDataReceivedEventHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort sData = sender as SerialPort;
            string recvData = sData.ReadLine();

            serialData.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { serialData.AppendText("受け取った :" + recvData); });
            double data;
            bool result = Double.TryParse(recvData, out data);
        }

        private void serialData_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            serialData.SelectionStart = serialData.Text.Length;
            serialData.ScrollToCaret();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort aSerialPort = new SerialPort("COM4");
            button1.Enabled = true;
            button2.Enabled = false;

            if (aSerialPort.IsOpen == true)
            {
                aSerialPort.Close();
            }
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label4.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
            timer1.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I went through this with you the last question you asked. You need to move the `SerialPort` out of the `button1_Click` handler and make it a field of the class. That way you can close it with the close button later. Right now you are making what is called a "zombie" object, something that can't be reached and is somehow still alive. And what do you mean by "meter" form? Like a needle/gauge? Or you want it to be displayed in meters (the measurement unit)?

Comment: @Ron Beyer thank you for your respond. yes meter means the measurement unit. i want to convert my sensor data on meter unit. Is there some formula or syntax or example for the conversion.?